# ISBLANK(Number Field) is not working

Tags: formula

I am trying to create a formula field to count if there are any blank values on Number field.

My formula is :

> if(ISBLANK(Number Field),1,0)

However, it is always coming as '0' even if the number field is having some value in the record.

Please advise as to where I am going wrong.

Comment: You can edit your own question, you do not need to add a comment. If you have anything to add/edit/change/fix/remove from your question, click on the: Edit link.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One assumption 
Vimal Go to the formula field edit it and scroll down to the last and see if you set 
Treat blank fields as zeroes if you did set it to "Treat blank fields as zeroes"

Set it to :

Treat blank fields as blanks

Hope this solves.

Comment: Yes, that did resolve the issue! However, I find it a little strange as it is a number field, I thought we should treat blank fields as zeroes. Any idea behind the explanation for that?

Comment: If your formula references any number, currency, or percent fields, specify what happens to the formula output when their values are blank.
When you say blank as 0's then technically the field is never blank