# Function to check whether a numeric field is blank

Tags: formula

IF(  ISBLANK(SIC_code__c ),0,8) is not working

Comment: Did you make sure that you selected "Count blanks as blanks" and not "Count blanks as zeroes?" If you're in the wrong "mode", then it'll never work.

Comment: already exist http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/isblanknumber-field-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Vipul,
Try this way

```
IF( ISBLANK(Text(SIC_code__c) ),0,8)
```

Comment: That won't help if the formula's in the wrong mode, because it'll be 0 instead of blank.